# About Group by day instruction for MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table, it is storing weather data from my weather station. It will record the data, such as rain, wind speed in every minute. The table format is date, time, rain, windspeed...., the rain is float. I want to know the total summary of rain in each day. However, when I use following instructions, the result are not same as my expectation. The total summary of rain of March 4 and Feb 4 are added up. I know I should not use group by day, but I don't know another instruction to prevent it.

```
SELECT date, sum(rain) AS sumRain 
FROM `XXX` 
where date>='2020-01-01' and rain>0 
group by day(date) 
order by date ASC
```

date sumRain
2020-02-04 5  <--the total rain summary at 2020-02-04 should be 3.75
2020-03-05 2.25

```
SELECT date, sum(rain) AS sumRain 
FROM `XXX` 
where date>='2020-02-05' and rain>0 
group by day(date) 
order by date ASC
```

date sumRain
2020-03-04 1.25

Comment: Does [day](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) do what you think it does? Or do you mean [date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)?

Comment: Hint `SELECT day(date) as day, count(*) as count, sum(rain) AS sumRain....`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be group data by Month and Day.

Try like this

```
SELECT date, sum(rain) AS sumRain 
FROM `XXX` 
where date>='2020-02-05' and rain>0 
group by day(date),month(date),year(date) 
order by date ASC
```

Comment: And `year` too?

Comment: Yess..Ideal GROUP BY should be on date column, instead of separating day, month and Year. Thanks for correcting :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I assume `date` column of your database is actually a `datetime`.

Because `DAY` is a function returning the day of month, grouping by this means 2020-02-05 and 2020-03-05 are the same day i.e. 5.

Alternately [date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) as a function removes the time aspect stored. Because `date` and `day` are functions, quoting needs to occur when you are referring to a column rather than a function.

MySQL allows you to use a SELECT result and GROUP BY/ORDER BY as the example below show. This enables the same code to work in 5.7 and 8.0 that gets strict on [sql_mode=only_full_group_by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) by default.

```
SELECT date(`date`) as `day`, sum(rain) AS sumRain 
FROM `XXX` 
where date>='2020-02-05' and rain>0 
group by `day`
order by `day` ASC
```